# XOR Neural network returning rubish

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, neural-network, xor, tensorflow.js

my XOR "neural network" in Tensorflow.js keeps returning **rubbish prediction** and the **loss** is always stuck at **0.25**. I have no idea what did I do wrong. Thank you for your help!

```js
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'sigmoid', inputShape: [2]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid'}));

model.compile({loss:'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
tf.train.sgd(0.5);

const xs = tf.tensor2d([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([[0],[1],[1],[0]]);

async function train() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        const history = await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 20, shuffle: true});
        console.log("loss: " + history.history.loss[19] + " on " + i + ". iteration.");
    }
}

train().then(() => {
    console.log("trained with " + tf.memory().numTensors + "tensors");
    model.predict(xs).print();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.13.0/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the optimizer and it predicts as expected.

```
    [[0.0156993],
     [0.985333 ],
     [0.9862437],
     [0.0150503]]
```

```js
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'sigmoid', inputShape: [2]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.01);
model.compile({loss:'meanSquaredError', optimizer: optimizer });

const xs = tf.tensor2d([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([[0],[1],[1],[0]]);

async function train() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        const history = await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 20, shuffle: true});
        console.log("loss: " + history.history.loss[19] + " on " + i + ". iteration.");
    }
}

train().then(() => {
    console.log("trained with " + tf.memory().numTensors + "tensors");
    model.predict(xs).print();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.13.0/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting! On my tablet it can get to 0.16 at best however on my iPad it mostly goes down to 0.002, however sometimes get stuck at 0.16 as well. Now I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: You mean the JS library behaves differently on different devices ?

Comment: Seems like it unfortunately does.